# box-shadow with Safari and Chrome and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari, css

There is some odd behaviour, when it comes to box shadows in Chrome and Safari.

When I use `box-shadow` the Chrome Browser in recent versions does support the CSS3 specification without the `-webkit-*` prefix, but the Safari browser doesn't.

This wouldn't be too bad, if Chrome simple would overwrite the  `-webkit-box-shadow` with the `box-shadow`, which it does, when both shadows are the same.

So to have my box shadow in Chrome *and* Safari, I need following.

```css
.some-class {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
```

which works fine in Safari and in Chrome and in FF and in Opera

But for IE9 the box shadow looks ugly. I must have a different box-shadow for IE9, something like `box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);` should be used

So my CSS is as follows

```css
.some-class {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
```

But I don't want the FF to have the IE9 box-shadow so I insert a CSS hack

```css
.some-class {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
/* IE9 */
@media all and (min-width:0) {
    .some-class  > ul.navigationlist{
         box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.35) \0/;
    }
}
```

---

now my question:
Is there a better way to do this? Except for Conditional Comments, which I know are designed for that, blah, blah...

---

edit
2nd question:
Do you all see the box-shadow in IE9 different to those in FF or Chrome, too?

---

edit
3rd question:
Is there a different prefix than `-ms-*` to use for `box-shadow` as `-ms-box-shadow` does not work?

Comment: Sorry to dissapoint you: conditional comments. Unless you're into setting CSS via JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you would cascade from vendor prefixes down to the standard property value, but in your case, I think you need to use the cascade effect in reverse and put the standard at the top and the vendor prefixes below, allowing the vendor specific to override the standard in all but IE.

```
.some-class {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
```

Comment: I did that already. The Problem is, that Chrome than has **two** shadows. The one from `box-shadow` and the one from `-webkit-box-shadow`. If the values of these would be the same, Chrome would have only one shadow, but if they differ, Chrome gets two shadows :( Try it for yourself with `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.65); box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);` in Chrome

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong: And it just looked, as if I had two shadows in Chrome

Comment: I don't have Chrome on my current system to test, so you may be seeing double. It appears that the `-moz-` version overrides http://jsfiddle.net/wfrcj/7/, but maybe `-webkit-` considers it two different things.

Comment: It's true: My eyes tricked on me. I just _thought_ there were two backgrounds on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

use `-moz-box-shadow` style for FF

**EDIT:** there is -ms prefix for some css3 styles, but not for all, unfortunately IE9 doesn't accept prefixed -ms-box-shadow, so you have to use conditional operators, but in case of other styles you can use that prefix, e.g. -ms-behavior,-ms-filter etc.

Answer (score -1):

Use a conditional comment to include a IE9 specific stylesheet:

```
<style>
/*regular css*/
</style>

<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess you overread the part of my questions, were I say, 'no conditional comment, I know about that'

Comment: @yunzen Why no conditional comments? They are perfect for this.

Comment: I thought of something, that makes the IE shadow more like the shadows in the others programms. I thought of a trick that I do not know. Conditional Comments is not that trick, because I know that already